# UITableView reloadData with UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following strange behavior. In didLoad() i have:

```
self.autocompleteTableView.delegate = self
self.autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self
```

where autocompleteTableView is the tableview id

with:

```
controller
    View
        autocompleteTableView
        Stack View
            textView
```

all run perfectly.

But with (I just move the view, the code stays as is):

```
controller
    View
        Stack View
            textView
            autocompleteTableView
```

the tableView does not refresh anymore, and the protocol is not fired.

I'm stuck!

Comment: Posting some code will definitely help since its hard to tell what causes this behavior without seeing code

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [simple, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.